# In eabean how to sort multiple column

Tags: java, playframework, ebean

In eabean how to sort by multiple column.

Ex: .orderBy().asc(field1).orderBy().asc(field2)

I am trying this but it  only considering field2 for sorting.

Answer (score 1):

```
Ebean.find(YourBean.class)
 .where()
  .eq("name", "test")
 .orderBy().desc("name, id")
.findList();
```

That's all you need to do separate the properties with commas.